# AWS SNS topic failing to send complete data to the subscribed AWS lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-sns

I have created an AWS SNS topic which is subscribed by a lambda.
To send the subscrpition I am calling the rest-api using postman and in the ***post body of rest api*** has a datatype and a representation.

*For ex* :  **datatype** is **com.hello.world** and **representation** is  **com.hello.world.india, com.hello.world.us, com.hello.world.uk**. The datatype remains same for all representations.

**Body of post method**
{

"endpoint": "lambda_arn",

"protocol":"lambda",

"event":"sns_topic",

"datatype":"com.hello.world",

"representation":"com.hello.world.india, com.hello.world.us, com.hello.world.uk,.....upto 75"
}

The issue is that when I am sending more than **75 representations** it gives me an error. However if I keep the count to 75, the post method successfully sends the data to the AWS SNS and there are names of those representation in the **subscription filter policy** of the  lambda subscription  in that sns topic.

Is there a limit in the AWS sns , that is set !!? Or is there a way I can resolve using other AWS services/ methods? or by using boto3 ?